# Construct a Ruby array with conditional logic inside

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can you construct an array in Ruby which only uses a variable if it exists, and otherwise uses `nil` in its place. With the conditional logic inside the array constructor.

**Simplified Example:**

```
a = 1
c = 3

arr = [a, b || nil, c]
```

I've tried a number of different way but they are not working so I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

1. `(b || nil)`
2. `b ? b : nil`
3. `b.nil? ? nil : b`

Is this possible?

**Context:**
This array constructor is used inside a loop used by multiple different models. Some models have the `b` attribute and some do not, making it difficult extrapolate the logic outside.

Comment: Why would `b` not exist? That's really an unusual thing to see in Ruby code.

Comment: You say both "uses a variable if it exists" and "Some models have the `b` attribute and some do not". The first says that `b` is a variable, the second says that `b` is a method call, which is it?

Comment: The real example is more similar to `@instance.attribute_b`. The method with this logic iterates over query results for several different models (separately); some of the models do not have an  `attribute_b`.

Comment: You shouldn't try to embed the conditional logic into the creation of the array; That way leads to madness at 3AM when a stressed coworker needs to fix a production bug. Instead, move the condition outside the array definition so it is clear what is happening, then define the array. Or, at a minimum, split the array into separate lines so there's some vertical space making it easier for the brain to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your `b` is actually a model attribute which may or may not be supported by the current `self`, then `b` is not a variable at all, `b` is a method call and you're not interested in whether or not the "variable" exists, you're interested in whether or not `self` responds to `b`. Hence you want to use [`respond_to?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F):

```
arr = [a, respond_to?(:b) ? b : nil, c]
```

or perhaps:

```
arr = [a, respond_to?(:b, true) ? b : nil, c]
```

if you want to allow `b` to be a non-public method.

`defined?(b)` should also work in this case (unless `b`'s accessor method is automatically created via `method_missing`) but it will be rather puzzling to anyone looking at your code. Using `respond_to?` to see if an object has a method/attribute would be more idiomatic.

Using `respond_to?` when faced with `method_missing` of course assumes that both `method_missing` and `respond_to?` have been overridden but that should be a relatively safe assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Yea, you can use `defined?` method. It return `"local-variable"`  if variable exist, if not it will return `nil`.

```
arr = [a, defined?(b) ? b : nil, c]
```

Comment: `arr = [a, defined?(b) ? b : nil, c]` is a little bit cleaner

Comment: This is the correct answer, as `b` is not guaranteed to be defined.

Comment: @CDub I understood this question exactly in this way.

Comment: The problem here is that `b` may not be defined but calling the `b` method could still work, consider a model that uses `method_missing` to create accessors as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
arr = [a, b = b || nil, c]
```

Example 1:

```
a = 1
c = 3

arr = [a, b = b || nil, c]
p arr #=> [1, nil, 3]
```

Example 2:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

arr = [a, b = b || nil, c]
p arr #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: can be shortened to  `arr = [a, b ||= nil, c]`

Comment: @Doon yes good point, I miss these things when trying to post a speedy answer. I will however not take up your recommendation as another answer has this already, but thank you.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 - go ahead and update it. You won't offend me. :)

Comment: In a code review I'd say that arr = [a, b = b || nil, c] is not easily read. While in C or Perl that sort of construct would fly, in Ruby we try to be more obvious. Breaking it into separate lines would help or preassign `b` then reference it in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

`arr = [a, (b ||= nil), c]`

Example:

```
a = 1
b = nil
c = 3

> arr = [a, (b ||= 33), c]
=> [1, 33, 3]

b = 2

> arr = [a, (b ||= 33), c]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

If `b` may not be defined, you'll need to use `defined?`:

```
> arr = [a, (defined?(b) ? b : nil), c]
=> [1, nil, 3]
```

Comment: It's not necessary to enclose the expression inside parenthesis, the commas will suffice, however for readability I'd put each element in the array on a separate line so it's easy to see what is happening.

Comment: While not necessary, on a single line, it's much easier to read and determine logic vs. simply a variable...

Comment: Yes, but it's questionable whether it should be a single line at all. Breaking it into multiple lines evaluates to the same thing, won't reduce speed but will improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Don't write code like that. Instead break it into more understandable pieces:

```
a = 1
c = 3

b ||= nil

arr = [a, b, c]
```

Or, use vertical space to help the brain see what's going on:

```
arr = [
  a,
  b ||= 3,
  c
]
```